# Using Latex CLSI to compile .tex files online

Tags: npm, latex, web-development-server

With some searching on the web, I found out that it is possible to install an online latex compiler to your website complete with front end editor and document storage.

The source: https://github.com/sharelatex/clsi-sharelatex

I have built my website by using JavaScript, HTML and PHP. It basically allows the user to make a resume with the use of Latex templates.

I am still a beginner to web development, but I am trying compile .tex files online without Latex being locally installed. I have read the above page on GitHub, but I don't seem to understand how to implement the Latex CLSI within a website.

I've searched the internet but I did not found any guides which could help me.
The following terms are unclear to me:

> $ git $ npm install $ grunt install

Does anyone have experience regarding this? A guide to implement the Latex 
CLSI would be helpfull, not only to me but also future readers.